# Does Wolverine's regenerative powers prevent him from successfully shaving?

Tags: marvel, x-men

Can Wolverine successfully shave, or does his facial hair regenerate too fast for him to even bother?

Comment: Off the top of my head... Facial (as well as head and body) hair isn't alive; just the root.  So it won't regenerate.  It's comparable to your fingernails; it's a product of the living root, not something alive itself.  Think of it like an exo-skeleton, if that helps. That's RL.. I have no canon backup to say the Marvel world works that way, but it seems likely.

Comment: I remember a comic from years ago in which sinister unseen doctors had captured Logan and were keeping him unconscious (somehow), preparing him for a medical procedure. One doctor criticized a nurse for not shaving the scalp properly; the nurse protested that he/she had, but it had already grown back to something like a sloppy crew-cut. It struck me as a very ill-considered plot point.

Comment: I'd put an answer on this question, but it's so inconsistent in the comics there's just no way to approach it. Multiple times Logan gets burned all to hell, then has his facial hair back within hours. Other times, when the plot requires it, Logan shaves off his chops and/or hair and it stays that way for hours if not days. And that's not even considering the fact that both chops and hair always grow back to the same length...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we ask our self another question: why does Logan never get older than THAT age and THAT physical appearance (or if he does, he does it veeeery slowly), we may be able to answer this question too.

He progressed from childhood to adulthood in a normal way but then his development kind of stopped and he never got older than he was at a certain point.

His hair and nails were also at a certain length and my guess is that **they grow back at the exact same length every time**, in the same way as his physical appearance is always the same.
The hair cut instead is only an author trick to avoid his needing to carry around a comb with him.

Comment: fisical -> physical, but he edit system won't let me do it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are some counter-examples of longhaired Logan in the comics, but I doubt it's worth disputing an accepted answer almost 4 years old.

Answer (score 4):

Keith has already clued it in comment... I am just elaborating it:
Mutant powers of Wolverine is attached with living cells, not dead cells like hair. So, hair tissues can't work against this damage. Plus... If you damage a dead tissue, there's no way for its producer glands to know about it (so that there's no pain due to this). So, it can't generate hair quickly as it doesn't know about this damage.

Comment: But then, how come he regenerates with a full head of hair after massive cranial trauma (and not bald)?

Comment: @HNL Possible explanation: When gland is destroyed, it knows how much hair it pumped out recently until destruction.. But, it can't explain hair-style.. :) So, it could be said `Plot Hole`.

Comment: I'm assuming this doesn't apply to sabertooth?

Comment: @HNL: Or after being briefly engulfed in flames? I'd say... because the writers love the hairstyle and have a low opinion of the intelligence of the readers.